# Couldn't find the correct provider above this widget

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I have a problem using Flutter Provider...

After Onbording screens I click to **Next Button** and needs to show me Welcome Screen (where i choose to log in with phone number)

But after clicking to **Next Button** i get this error - *Could not find the correct Provider above this WelcomeScreen Widget*

```
class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ap = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: true);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
```

Comment: Can you include your main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Provider<> widget is present and at the root(like parent of MaterialApp for instance) to make sure it is in widget tree across rebuilds.

As far as I can see your code, you're calling Provider watch in welcome screen which prolly doesn't have the Provider in its tree. Move the watch to OnboardingScreen.